# Remove headers on a float page containing a single big float with footnotes

Tags: floats, header-footer, footnotes, fancyhdr

I'd like to remove headers (inserted by `fancyhdr` package) on a float page that contains a single big figure with footnotes.

I'd like to retain the same pagination and content flow, i.e. forced use of a `\clearpage` before the figure is not an option. I tried the `afterpage` package and wrapped my float in an `afterpage` environment, but this fails with a weird `file not found` error thrown by `includegraphics`.

Here is my `MWE`. The float page is the 2nd page, from which the header line/rule is to be removed. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand{\mpfootnotes}[1][1]{
  \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\thefootnote}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-#1}
  \renewcommand{\footnote}{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]}}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% debug only
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\setFancyHdr}{
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. ##1 }}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{{\bfseries\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \fancyhead{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\setFancyHdr

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[p]      % the figure needs to occupy the entire page. Hence permitting only the 'p' modifier. 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textwidth]{demo} % 'fig_master_flow_diagramPDF.pdf' is a huge figure and needs to stretch/shrink suitably to occupy the entire type-area available.
        \caption
        [%
        Interesting caption
        ]%
        {%
             Interesting caption\footnotemark.
        }%
        \label{fig:fig_strategy_schematic}
        \mpfootnotes[1]
        \footnote{Some important footnote}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: see section 13 of fancyhdr doc, shows how to specify page style for float pages, you want page style `empty`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  yup, I read that section and tried out a few things before posting here. Did you mean `\iffloatpage{{\pagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{fancy}}}`? Obviously, I cannot use `empty` because I need page numbers in the footer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried `\iffloatpage{\pagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{fancy}}`. This does not work.

Comment: no see the doc again the header specification  needs to be something like `\iffloatpage{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}` so it only uses the normal head on non-float pages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried that too. If the float happens on the left page, this fails.

Comment: But this works, when used as the last command in the preamble, `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}`

Comment: well yes that is `[R]` you need to do the same for `[L]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to suppress headers for float pages containing only figures? i.e. the headers in float pages containing only tables shall remain intact.

Comment: no (not easily)

Comment: Hmm.... Is it possible to hack together something with maybe Lua magic?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have posted this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449698/remove-headers-from-a-float-page-with-figure-but-not-with-tables). Maybe there is someone crazy enough to hack at this.

Comment: you would I think need to extend the latex output routine so that it knows what is in the page. Currently when it adds a figure it has no way of knowing if the existing stuff is a figure or a table or a listing or whatever.

Comment: in any real case you can go `\clearpage \thispagestyle[plain}\begin{figure}....`

Comment: Yes. But that breaks the paragraph flow, without `afterpage`. But with `afterpage`, the footnote macro doesn't work.

Comment: it's your document, wait till the end and spend 5 minutes placing the forced break at the optimal position. If you were implementing an automatic workflow processing thousands of documents a day with no manual supervision, then things would be different,